# Installed cordova-plugin-file-transfer causing Android build failure

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, phonegap-plugins

My `ionic info` environment:

cli packages: (C:\Users\jessica\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 5.0.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.10.3
npm               : 6.0.1
OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy`
```

After installing `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer`, I am getting below error when I run the command `ionic cordova build android`

> :compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have
>   changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:49:
>   error: package org.apache.cordova.file does not exist import
>   org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils;
>                                 ^ F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:851:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>                     FileUtils filePlugin = (FileUtils) pm.getPlugin("File");
>                     ^   symbol: class FileUtils F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:851:
> ```
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>                           FileUtils filePlugin = (FileUtils) pm.getPlugin("File");
>                                                   ^   symbol: class FileUtils Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note:
>   F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. 3 errors :compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 48.087 secs
>
> (node:6372) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code
>   1 Error output: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated
>   API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some
>   input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:49:
>   error: package org.apache.cordova.file does not exist import
>   org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils;
>                                 ^ F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:851:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                           FileUtils filePlugin = (FileUtils) pm.getPlugin("File");
>                           ^   symbol: class FileUtils F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:851:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                           FileUtils filePlugin = (FileUtils) pm.getPlugin("File");
>                                                   ^   symbol: class FileUtils Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note:
>   F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-android\quicktask\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. 3 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: As you can see from the spurious Markdown formatting, quote blocks are not ideal ways to format exceptions/logs here. I would recommend code/block formatting instead to produce the most readable format.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, which is caused by the low version of cordova-android. If you are in ionic cordova platform add android, have noticed that cordova-plugin-file is required for cordova-android version greater than or equal to 6.3.0.

So just run the command:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

This will be packaged successfully after running the ionic build.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of some android support version. If you check your android project in some android studio IDE, you can see the version of android support, which is not compatible with the version used by that File plugin.

You can use the `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` plugin, it can help you set the correct version during building. You can google it about how to use it.

Comment: I use visual studio to code, i should now download android studio and proceed ? I created a blank ionic project, imported this file and build apk, there was no error, but its version was android 7.0.0, now if i update by current project to 7.0.0 i get different errors 

Comment: no need. android support version is not android version. As I said above, the error is because of the plugin and app use different android support version. You can check which version you use and see the place which is incompatible.    Just try the plugin I said, to check whether it can solve your problem.